# component wont render when is useEffect() is ran once

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-google-charts

So I have the following code, where I'm fetching data to be rendered in my component. However, if the useEffect is set to run once, it wont render the data inside the component, and having it constantly running is not sustainable.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Chart from "react-google-charts";


const Bottom5 = ({ company }) => {
    const [quiz, setQuiz] = useState('');
    const [dataPoints, setDatapoints] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
            var resultData = [];
            fetch(`http://localhost:3001/company/dashboard/bottom5/${company}`)
            .then(function(response) {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(function(data) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    resultData.push({
                        label: data[i].name,
                        y: data[i].sumCorrect
                    });
                }
               setDatapoints(resultData)
            });
    },[])


    return (
            <Chart style={{display:"inline-block"}}
                width={'500px'}
                height={'300px'}
                chartType="ColumnChart"
                loader={<div>Loading Chart</div>}
                data={[
                    ['Names', 'Result'],
                    ...dataPoints.map(d => [d.label, d.y])
                ]}
                options={{
                    title: 'CyberSecurity Bottom 5',
                    chartArea: { width: '50%' },
                    hAxis: {
                        title: 'Employees',
                        minValue: 0,
                    },
                    vAxis: {
                        title: 'Total Correct',
                    },
                }}
                // For tests
                rootProps={{ 'data-testid': '1' }}
            />
    )
}

export default Bottom5;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be that when you first mount the component you have not passed a `company` to it ?

Normally since the code depends on the value of `company`, it is a good idea to add `company` to the `useEffect` dependency list.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  var resultData = [];
  if (company) {
    fetch(`http://localhost:3001/company/dashboard/bottom5/${company}`)
      .then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(function(data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          resultData.push({
            label: data[i].name,
            y: data[i].sumCorrect
          });
        }
        setDatapoints(resultData)
      });
  }
}, [company])
```

This way it will only be called whenever the `company` property is changed.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with update the array using hooks.

```
setDatapoints(resultData) // reference is same - not updating
setDatapoints([...resultData]) // do this << --
```

The reference of an array does not change, so hooks doesn't update itself.

Comment: it is not the same. The state variable is `dataPoints` not `resultData`